# Kivy application login

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy and I have built a simple app with 2 screens. The first screen is also the login screen and the second screen just shows a simple label. I want to use Twitter/Google authentication to login and move on to the second screen.

Should I use a button (with image) and use the on_release function call or should I use a plain image file and hook it up with an on_touch_down event to call the authentication process?

What is the standard way to do it? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's entirely up to you, but in the absence of other concerns default to the Button.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest you dive into kivyMD( a kivy frameworks that makes the job easier) adding beautiful interface to the program. what you want is just a 4 line code in KivyMD